# Share a c++ library on Mac OS X so I can add user defined functions to mySQL

Tags: c++, macos

I am trying to add my own user defined functions to mySQL following the instructions:
[enter link description here](http://mysql-udf.sourceforge.net/)

But it does not work so far in my mac OS X mavericks.

I first do:

```
gcc -Wall -I /usr/local/mysql/include -I /usr/local/include -c udf_median.cc -o udf_median.o
```

Then I try:

```
ld -shared -o udf_median.so udf_median.o
```

But I get an error:

```
ld: unknown option: -shared
```

Is there anyway to share a library in Mac os X?

I tried as suggested in answer and I geT:

```
ld -dylib -o udf_median.dylib udf_median.o
ld: warning: -macosx_version_min not specified, assuming 10.8
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__ZdlPv", referenced from:
      _median_deinit in udf_median.o
  "__Znwm", referenced from:
      _median_init in udf_median.o
  "_free", referenced from:
      _median_deinit in udf_median.o
      _median_reset in udf_median.o
  "_malloc", referenced from:
      _median_reset in udf_median.o
  "_qsort", referenced from:
      _median in udf_median.o
  "_realloc", referenced from:
      _median_add in udf_median.o
  "_strcpy", referenced from:
      _median_init in udf_median.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for inferred architecture x86_64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mac OS X linker uses the `-dylib` flag for this. Additionally, the platform uses the `.dylib` extension for shared libraries, not `.so`.

```
ld -dylib -o udf_median.dylib udf_median.o
```

Since you are invoking the linker directly, you may also need to add flags to link against libraries that are normally implicit (e.g, `-lc` for libc). Alternatively, if your library links against functions present in the parent executable, you may need to use other linker options to allow this to take place.

Comment: Hi, thanks! i still get an error, not sure why, i put the error in Q

Comment: Updated; short version: `-lc` will take care of all but the first two, which look like a C++ issue?

Comment: thanks you are right.  the first two seems a compatibility issue between mac os X and linux C++...